# str not callable error. I am making a dog top trumps code in python, I was wondering if anyone knew why I was getting this error

Tags: python

```
import random as r
Pdeck = []
Cdeck = []
options = ["e", "i", "f", "d"]
counter = 0
num = 0

with open("dogs.txt") as file:
    names = file.readlines()
    names = [line.rstrip() for line in names]

r.shuffle(names)

def play():
    global Pdeck, Cdeck, counter, pGo, num
    if Pdeck[counter+num] > Cdeck[counter+num]:
        print("~You win the round!~")
        pGo = True
        if not Cdeck:
            print("#You win!#")
        else:
            for i in range(0,5):
                Pdeck.append(Cdeck[counter+i])
            for i in range(0,5):
                Cdeck.pop(counter+i)
    elif Pdeck[counter+num] < Cdeck[counter+num]:
        print("~The computer wins this round.~")
        pGo = False
        if not Pdeck:
            print("#The computer wins.#")
        else:
            for i in range(0,5):
                Cdeck.append(Cdeck[counter+i])
            for i in range(0,5):
                Pdeck.pop(counter+i)
    else:
        print("~It's a draw! No change.~")
    return Pdeck, Cdeck, pGo, num

while True:
    print("~~~Welcome to Doggie top trumps!~~~\n~~~Would you like to (p)lay or (q)uit?")
    play = input("> ").lower()
    if play == "q":
        break
    elif play == "p":
        print("~~~How many cards would you like to play with?~~~")
        cardsToPlay = int(input("> "))
        if cardsToPlay < 4 or cardsToPlay > 30:
            print("~Please select a value greater than 4 or less than 30~")
        elif cardsToPlay % 2 == 1:
            print("~Please select an even number~")
        else:
            for i in range(0, cardsToPlay):
                if i % 2 == 1:
                    Pdeck.append(names[i])
                    Pdeck.append(r.randint(1,5))
                    Pdeck.append(r.randint(1,100))
                    Pdeck.append(r.randint(1,10))
                    Pdeck.append(r.randint(1,10))
                else:
                    Cdeck.append(names[i])
                    Cdeck.append(r.randint(1,5))
                    Cdeck.append(r.randint(1,100))
                    Cdeck.append(r.randint(1,10))
                    Cdeck.append(r.randint(1,10))
            pGo = True
            while True:
                num = 0
                if pGo == True:
                    print("~~It's your turn.~~\n~Here is your card.~\n")
                    print(Pdeck[counter],"\nEXERCISE:",Pdeck[counter+1],"\nINTELLIGENCE:",Pdeck[counter+2],"\nFRIENDLINESS:",Pdeck[counter+3],"\nDROOL:",Pdeck[counter+4]," (lowest)\n")
                    print("~What category would you like (e,i,f,d)")
                    categ = input("> ").lower()
                    if categ == "e":
                        num = 0
                    elif categ == "i":
                        num = 1
                    elif categ == "f":
                        num = 2
                    elif categ == "d":
                        if Pdeck[counter+3] < Cdeck[counter+3]:
                            print("~You win the round!~")
                            pGo = True
                            if not Cdeck:
                                print("#You win!#")
                            else:
                                for i in range(0,5):
                                    Pdeck.append(Cdeck[counter+i])
                                for i in range(0,5):
                                    Cdeck.pop(counter+i)
                        elif Pdeck[counter+3] > Cdeck[counter+3]:
                            print("~The computer wins this round.~")
                            pGo = False
                            if not Pdeck:
                                print("#The computer wins.#")
                            else:
                                for i in range(0,5):
                                    Cdeck.append(Cdeck[counter+i])
                                for i in range(0,5):
                                    Pdeck.pop(counter+i)
                        else:
                            print("~It's a draw! No change.~")
                    else:
                        print("Please select a numid option")
                    play()
                else:
                    print("~~It's the compuer's turn.~~\n~Here is your card.~\n")
                    print(Pdeck[counter],"\nEXERCISE:",Pdeck[counter+1],"\nINTELLIGENCE:",Pdeck[counter+2],"\nFRIENDLINESS:",Pdeck[counter+3],"\nDROOL:",Pdeck[counter+4]," (lowest)\n")
                    print("~~Here is the computer's card:~~\n")
                    print(Cdeck[counter],"\nEXERCISE:",Cdeck[counter+1],"\nINTELLIGENCE:",Cdeck[counter+2],"\nFRIENDLINESS:",Cdeck[counter+3],"\nDROOL:",Cdeck[counter+4]," (lowest)\n")
                    choice = r.choice(options)
                    categ = choice
                    if choice == "e":
                        chosen = "exercise"
                    elif choice == "i":
                        chosen = "intelligence"
                    elif choice == "f":
                        chosen = "friendliness"
                    elif choice == "d":
                        chosen = "drool"
                    print("The computer has chosen the category: ", chosen)
                    if categ == "e":
                        num = 0
                    elif categ == "i":
                        num = 1
                    elif categ == "f":
                        num = 2
                    elif categ == "d":
                        if Pdeck[counter+3] < Cdeck[counter+3]:
                            print("~You win the round!~")
                            pGo = True
                            if not Cdeck:
                                print("#You win!#")
                            else:
                                for i in range(0,5):
                                    Pdeck.append(Cdeck[counter+i])
                                for i in range(0,5):
                                    Cdeck.pop(counter+i)
                        elif Pdeck[counter+3] > Cdeck[counter+3]:
                            print("~The computer wins this round.~")
                            pGo = False
                            if not Pdeck:
                                print("#The computer wins.#")
                            else:
                                for i in range(0,5):
                                    Cdeck.append(Cdeck[counter+i])
                                for i in range(0,5):
                                    Pdeck.pop(counter+i)
                        else:
                            print("~It's a draw! No change.~")
                    else:
                        print("Please select a valid option")
                    play()
    else:
        print("~Please select a valid option~")
```

Anyone know what is causing this error? I run it and after it displays the card and lets me choose the categories it displays string not callable error.:

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

I have only been doing python for about a year or two so still relatively new, and it's GCSE level, but for fun. Would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Your code is not reproducible, your should at least provide the full error traceback

Comment: File "c:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\dog top trumps\dogtrumps.py", line 105, in <module>
    play()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Assigning to the name `play` replaces the function previously bound to that name. Pick a different function name or variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 14 of your code, you define a function called `play()`.

```
def play():
```

However, on line 42, you assign `play` as a string:

```
play = input("> ").lower()
```

Finally, on line 105, you try to call the `play()` function. Change the variable on line 42 to a different name (and update the other places in the code where that string variable is referenced), and you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of this on line 42. Either rename the function or rename the variable.

```
play = input("> ").lower()
```